# Filtering associated values in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Suppose you have a huge dataset with pupils and the classes that they attend. I want to create a filter where, when you filter on pupils, only the classes that they attend are shown. However, I also want to keep the other pupils who attend those indirectly filtered classes.

**Example**

Dataset:

| Pupil ID | Class ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| etc. | etc |

So when I filter on **Pupil ID = 1**, the output should be:

| Pupil ID | Class ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| etc. | etc |

My thought process so far is that each class is a group, and each group is overlapping. By choosing a Pupil ID, you indirectly choose a set of groups.

Does anyone have an idea as to how to avoid removing the non-selected pupils within the groups which are indirectly chosen by the selected (filtered) pupil?

**Note:** I have built the data model so that there are DIM_Pupil and DIM_Class tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity, let's say that the data from your example above all lives in one table (**Table**). The problem is, if you're filtering based on Table[Pupil ID], then you're literally telling Power BI that the only thing you want to see is rows with the selected Pupil ID(s).

To work around this, you need to create a new table and associate it in such a way that you can filter how you would like. In your case, create a new table (ex. **Filter**), which looks the exact same as your original **Table**. Then, in Power BI's model tab, associate Table[Class ID] to Filter[Class ID] in a **many-to-many** relationship.

**Table**

| Pupil ID | Class ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| etc. | etc |

**Filter**

| Pupil ID | Class ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 |
| etc. | etc |

**Class ID <--> Class ID**

[image: Table Connection]

Now all you need to do is display your data using the **Table** table and filter your data using the **Filter[Pupil ID]** column. This will give you the result that you want.

Note that this solution will need to be adjusted slightly based on your actual table structure, but the concept remains the same.

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Comment: However, i am on PBI Report Server, where many-to-many relationships are still not introduced (thanks MS). 
But, by following your table structure and just incorporated a "bridge table" (constituting unique class ID's) between the "filter table" and the "table", where both "Filter table" and "Table" have many-to-one relationships to the bridge (and thus indirectly many-to-many between "Filter table" and "Table"). Note: both relationships to the bridge need to crossfilter in both directions.